# How to use brackets as a hot key in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to use a square bracket as a hotkey to send some text:

```
#o:: SendText "Something"  ; This works
#[:: SendText "Something"  ; 'Error, invalid hotkey'
```

Is it possible to do this?

Here's some things I've tried:

```
#`[::         ; using escape tilde - script won't run
#SC01A::      ; using key's hex value - prints `[`, not `Something`
```

*PS: I'm using AHK v2.0.2*

Comment: Try it in a script with only that code and no other script running, in case something else interferes.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following should work.

```
$[::
SendText "Something"

return
```

Comment: This kinda worked, in that it sent "Something" whenever I pressed the [ button, but it did not work as intended, using the windows key: `#$[::`, again it just sent `[`

Comment: Your question only mentions about using square brackets to send something. What is the intended behavior? What do you mean by "using the windows key", is that win + [ ?

Comment: Yes, `#[::` is the intended behavior, please see my question.

Comment: Does `#^[::` work?